# Load resource from Assembly without loading the Assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I looking for an API to extract a resource from an assembly but don’t want to load the assembly itself, not even in a separate AppDomain.

Is there a way of reading Assembly ManifestResourceStreams that isn’t `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`, which requires loading the Assembly?

Example of what I’m looking for:

```cs
var r = new AssemblyResourceReader(“Test.dll”);
Stream s = r.GetResourceStream(“image.png”);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why you do not want to load the complete Assembly?

Comment: I have encountered several reasons: incompatibility, performance, for example. Or imagine for example that you have 100 dlls in a plug-in directory and want to list them, displaying a thumbnail each has as a resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found an answer: the System.Reflection.Metadata package has such utilities

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;

public static class AssemblyMetadataReader
{      
   public static byte[] GetManifestResource(string asmPath, string resourceName)
   {
      using (var fs = File.OpenRead(asmPath))
      {
         PEReader per = new PEReader(fs);
         MetadataReader mr = per.GetMetadataReader();
         foreach (var resHandle in mr.ManifestResources)
         {
            var res = mr.GetManifestResource(resHandle);
            if (!mr.StringComparer.Equals(res.Name, resourceName))
               continue;
         
            PEMemoryBlock resourceDirectory = per.GetSectionData(per.PEHeaders.CorHeader.ResourcesDirectory.RelativeVirtualAddress);
            var reader = resourceDirectory.GetReader((int)res.Offset, resourceDirectory.Length - (int)res.Offset);
            uint size = reader.ReadUInt32();
            return reader.ReadBytes((int)size);
         }
      }
      return null;
   }      
}
```

Comment: So you get an array of bytes and then what do you do with it?

Comment: The bytes are what I was after . They are the resource. If it's representing a block of text or a snippet of audio or a thumbnail image isn't important.  Once you have the bytes you can  easily do anything like just load an image from it.

Answer (score 0):

Found this from another answer :

You can use some API, for example [CCI](https://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) that allows you to look inside managed dll(s) without loading it using reflection mechanism.

Ref : [how to read the assembly manifest without loading the .dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212801/how-to-read-the-assembly-manifest-without-loading-the-dll)

Comment: Can you please add the link to the other answer? That link might add a little bit more context to your answer.

Comment: I think this should be added as comment with duplicate

Comment: Added reference to that answer. Thanks for suggesting.